# react navigation hide header icon for some screens

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

i use bottom tab bar and for the first screens i don't want to show back button icon.

and i used header at the top of tab.navigator

is there a easy way to do it

```
const AccountStack = ({navigation}) => {
  return (
    <>
      <View>
        <Icon                // this the back button 
          name="chevron-left"
          type="font-awesome"
          color={'#ffffff'}
          onPress={() => {
            navigation.pop();
          }}
        />
        <Image
          style={{height: 30, width: 170}}
          source={require('./src/assets/logo-white.png')}
        />
      </View>
      <Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={'WinterStack'}
        screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false,
          tabBarShowLabel: true,
          animation: 'fade',
        }}>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="WinterStack"
          component={WinterStack}/>

        <Tab.Screen
          name="SummerStack"
          component={SummerStack}/>

        <Tab.Screen
          name="SettingsStack"
          component={SettingsStack}/>
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the View with the back button inside header on 'screenOptions' on Tab.Navigator, then set 'headerShown:false' on Tab.Screen to not show the header on the screen you want.

```
<Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={'WinterStack'}
    screenOptions={{
      header:()=> `ENTER YOUR VIEW HERE`,
      headerShown: true,
      tabBarShowLabel: true,
      animation: 'fade',
    }}>
    <Tab.Screen
      name="WinterStack"
      component={WinterStack}
      options={{
        headerShown:false,
      }}
      />
```

Comment: that doesn't work

Comment: Instead of just saying "it doesn't work", provide a description of what you encountered when you tried their answer so that they can update their answer if needed.

Comment: Thanks Joshua, could you describe the error you got @yasin, it should work.. I took it from a code snippet with the same problem, I tested it before posting the answer and here it worked!